# Redirect / rewrite domain in Wildfly 9

Tags: redirect, url-rewriting, wildfly, wildfly-9

How can I configure Wildfly to redirect from olddomain.com to newdomain.com? I know this can be done in apache through htaccess, but I have no idea which configuration files need to be edited in Wildfly and how to configure them.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: No, I just switched to Apache. Two simple lines in Apache's configuration file (vhosts) and it works exactly how I expect. Wildfly is really hard to configure and its documentation is also very unclear...